# mocha, sinon and stubbing out the window object

Tags: webpack, mocha.js, aws-sdk, sinon

I have an ES6 module that I am trying to write tests for that is for a front-end react/redux app.

Here is the part of the module that is tripping me up in my tests:

```
import 'aws-sdk/dist/aws-sdk';
import Bluebird from 'bluebird';

const AWS = window.AWS;
```

Here is the beginning of my tests:

```
import chai from 'chai';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import chaiAsPromised from 'chai-as-promised';
import sinon from 'sinon';

chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

describe("S3Gateway", () => {
  let awsStub;
  let sandbox;
  let writeObject;

  beforeEach(() => {
    sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
    writeObject = require('../../../app/lib/aws/s3gateway').writeObject;

    awsStub = sinon.stub().returns({
      S3: sinon.stub().returns({
        putObject: sinon.spy()
      })
    });
    sandbox.stub(window, 'AWS', awsStub);
  });
```

The error I keep getting in my stdout from running mocha in my terminal window is:

```
$ mocha test/lib/aws/s3gateway.js --compilers js:babel-core/register


  S3Gateway
    1) "before each" hook for "should attempt to write json object to s3"


  0 passing (483ms)
  1 failing

  1) S3Gateway "before each" hook for "should attempt to write json object to s3":
     ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

The reason for having to get `AWS` from the `window` object is because of the way webpack bundles the aws-sdk for front-end apps. Anyone else run into this issue and fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

mocha tests run in node.js, and node.js does not have a global window variable. But you can easily create one in your tests:

```
global.window = {};
```

You can even fill it immediately with what you want to have in your test:

```
global.window = {AWS: /* insert your test data here*/ }
```

and that should do.

If you need a more realistic window, you should look into using jsdom.

Comment: Ah, `global.window` is what I am missing. Let me give that a try! Thanks!!